# Invalid license for MuleSoft DataMapper

Tags: mule

Iam trying to deploy my mule application war in weblogic server, Its failing by giving below exception.

We do have license. Please let me know how to Deploy in weblogic server by installing license.

**Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException: Invalid license for MuleSoft DataMapper, please contact MuleSoft info@mulesoft.com**

`

```
    Mar 19, 2014 3:32:32 PM IST> <Error> <ServletContext-/MyApplication-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT> <BEA-000000> <Error creating bean with name 'TestReqFlow': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)' of type [org.mule.config.spring.factories.FlowRefFactoryBean] while setting bean property 'messageProcessors' with key [1]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'InvocationFlowRef': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException: Invalid licensefor MuleSoft DataMapper, please contact MuleSoft info@mulesoft.com (org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException)
org.mule.api.config.ConfigurationException: Error creating bean with name 'TestReqFlow'
: Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)' of type org.mule.config.spring.factories.FlowRefFactoryBean] while setting bean property 'messageProcessors' with key [1]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'InvocationFlowRef': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException: Invalid license for MuleSoft DataMapper, please contact MuleSoft info@mulesoft.com (org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException)
        at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:52)     at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.java:78)        at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.createMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:103)        at org.mule.config.builders.MuleXmlBuilderContextListener.createMuleContext(MuleXmlBuilderContextListener.java:169)        at org.mule.config.builders.MuleXmlBuilderContextListener.initialize(MuleXmlBuilderContextListener.java:98)    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace Caused By: org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException: Error creating bean with name 'TestReqFlow': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)' of type [org.mule.config.spring.factories.FlowRefFactoryBean] while setting bean property'messageProcessors' with key [1]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.
factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'InvocationFlowRef': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException: Invalid license for MuleSoft DataMapper, please contact MuleSoft info@mulesoft.com        at org.mule.registry.AbstractRegistry.initialise(AbstractRegistry.java:1
17)        at org.mule.config.spring.SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.createSpringRegi
stry(SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.java:119)        at org.mule.config.spring.SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.doConfigure(Spri
ngXmlConfigurationBuilder.java:73)        at org.mule.config.builders.WebappMuleXmlConfigurationBuilder.doConfigure(WebappMuleXmlConfigurationBuilder.java:82)        at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:46)        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace Caused By: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creati
ng bean with name 'TestReqFlow': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)' of type[org.mule.config.spring.factories.FlowRefFactoryBean] while setting bean property 'messageProcessors' with key [1]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework. beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'InvocationFlowRef': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException: Invalid license for MuleSoft DataMapper, please contact MuleSoft info@mulesoft.com        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:282)        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:126)        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:353)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver
.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:154)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
Factory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1391)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creati
ng bean with name '(inner bean)': Invocation of init method failed; nested excep
tion is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating
bean with name 'InvocationFlowRef': Invocation of init method failed; nested
 exception is org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException: Invalid license fo
r MuleSoft DataMapper, please contact MuleSoft info@mulesoft.com
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
Factory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1486)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
Factory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
Factory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver
.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:271)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver
.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:126)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creati
ng bean with name 'InvocationFlowRef': Invocation of init method failed; nes
ted exception is org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException: Invalid license
 for MuleSoft DataMapper, please contact MuleSoft info@mulesoft.com
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
Factory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1486)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
Factory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
Factory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getOb
ject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistr
y.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException: Invalid license for M
uleSoft DataMapper, please contact MuleSoft info@mulesoft.com
        at com.mulesoft.mule.module.datamapper.processors.DataMapperMessageProce
ssor.initialise(DataMapperMessageProcessor.java:84)
        at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.initialise(Abs
tractMessageProcessorChain.java:83)
        at org.mule.construct.AbstractFlowConstruct.initialiseIfInitialisable(Ab
stractFlowConstruct.java:318)
        at org.mule.construct.AbstractPipeline.doInitialise(AbstractPipeline.jav
a:212)
        at org.mule.construct.AbstractFlowConstruct$1.onTransition(AbstractFlowC
onstruct.java:113)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: com.mulesource.licm.impl.InvalidLicenseKeyException: de.schlichtherle
.license.NoLicenseInstalledException: There is no license certificate installed
for MuleSource Enterprise Edition.
        at com.mulesource.licm.impl.TrueLicenseHelper.validateLicenseKey(TrueLic
enseHelper.java:233)
        at com.mulesource.licm.impl.MuleLicenseManager.validate(MuleLicenseManag
er.java:61)
        at com.mulesoft.mule.module.datamapper.boot.DataMapperLicenseCheck.loadL
icenseKey(DataMapperLicenseCheck.java:23)
        at com.mulesoft.mule.module.datamapper.boot.DataMapperLicenseCheck.check
DMEntitlement(DataMapperLicenseCheck.java:35)
        at com.mulesoft.mule.module.datamapper.processors.DataMapperMessageProce
ssor.initialise(DataMapperMessageProcessor.java:78)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: de.schlichtherle.license.NoLicenseInstalledException: There is no lic
ense certificate installed for MuleSource Enterprise Edition.
        at de.schlichtherle.license.ftp.LicenseManager.verify(Unknown Source)
        at de.schlichtherle.license.LicenseManager.verify(Unknown Source)
        at com.mulesource.licm.impl.TrueLicenseHelper.validateLicenseKey(TrueLic
enseHelper.java:228)
        at com.mulesource.licm.impl.MuleLicenseManager.validate(MuleLicenseManag
er.java:61)
        at com.mulesoft.mule.module.datamapper.boot.DataMapperLicenseCheck.loadL
icenseKey(DataMapperLicenseCheck.java:23)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

`

Comment: I would contact Mulesoft support directly.
Make sure you license file is on the classpath of your appliation and exported with your war file and verify your license as outlined here: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Installing+an+Enterprise+License

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mulesoft provides documentation for deploying a Mule application within WebLogic:
http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Deploying+Mule+to+WebLogic

and to install an Enterprise license:
http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Installing+an+Enterprise+License

However, if you do have an Enterprise license, you can also contact Mulesoft directly as part of your support package.

Answer (score 2):

DataMapper is a Mule Enterprise feature. You should contact MuleSoft Support if you do have a subscription.

Answer (score 0):

Full DataMapper functionality is exclusive to the Mule ESB Enterprise Edition (EE), it won't work if you're deploying your projects to Mule ESB Community Edition (CE).

Please contact MuleSoft to include Data Mapper as an entitlement to your subscription.

Let me know if you need further details.

Sanjeet Pandey